# My Windows Forms buttons are not displaying as I want

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application and I'm trying to add buttons to mimic a calculator.

```
public class myform : Form
{
    public myform()
    {
        //setting size of form
        this.Text = "Calculator";
        this.Height = 600;
        this.Width = 400;

        //creating buttons from 0-9
        Button[] b = new Button[10];
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        string ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        {
            ch = Convert.ToString(i);
            x = 0;
            y = y + 50;
            b[i] = new Button();
            b[i].Height = 40;
            b[i].Width = 40;
            b[i].Text = ch;
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                x = x + 50;
                b[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(b[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

here is the form class in which i am creating the object of myform class described above.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        myform mf = new myform();
        mf.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try looking into a `TableLayoutPanel`

Comment: if you can't describe the problem more precisely we can't really help you

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you always set the x value to x = x + 150; I suggest you change your x value to x = (i%3) * 50; and your y to y= (i/3) *50;
that should provide you with a nice array of buttons.

```
        ch = Convert.ToString(i);
        x = (i%3)*50;
        y = (i/3)*50;
        b[i] = new Button();
        b[i].Height = 40;
        b[i].Width = 40;
        b[i].Text = ch;
        b[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
```

Will be your new loop body.

Comment: @saad bin sami . Make sure to mark as answer for prof1990 :)